# Back up and restore in wss 3.0

Tags: tfs

I have wss3.0 installed and have integrated Team foundation server with it.
I am facing difficulty during recovery. 
When i try to create a new Team Foundation Project(as a part of recovery steps) in Visual Studio for installed Team foundation server, it throws following error:
An unexpected error occurred: TF50309: The following account does not have suffi
cient permissions to complete the operation: xyz\abc. Check the permissio
ns for the account and grant the appropriate permissions to perform this operati
on.

Can someone please help on this.

Note:
1) I have changed the Identity Attribute in application pool, it doesnt works.
2) Visual Studio is running with administrator rights.
3) logged on user is having administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have rights on the sharepoint site collection to create a new site?